# Good way to handle "expirable" objects stored in the Dictionary?

Tags: .net, time, timer

Have the following problem: storing into `Dictionary` objects that have lifetime limit of ~20 minutes(time precision is not crucial). After that, object should be deleted from the `Dictionary`.

I can create queue or an array that will be periodically checked for upcoming "kill" time, but was hoping to find simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me I create a second Dictionary of  `DateTime, List<keysfrom1>`
Have the key to the minute (or every 20 minutes).
Every minute (or 20 minutes) look up the Values to delete.